# relative path to project root directory of log4net log file in C# Class Library Project

Tags: c#, log4net

I am creating a C# class library project which will be used by other projects. I want to have this class library to have its own logging as other projects may or may not have logging. I am using log4net nuget for this purpose. After going through various tutorials I am able to generate log and log4net.config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="log4net.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <!-- Setup Rolling Log File to log all information -->
    <appender name="DebugFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <param name="File" value="C:\Users\Karan\Desktop\MyProject\log.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date"/>
      <param name="DatePattern" value="_yyyy-MM.\tx\t"/>
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="DebugFileAppender" />
    </root>

  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I added config file info in AssemblyInfor.cs like this

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

This is generating log file but I would like to have the log file generated to the relative path of the project which is using this library. I do not have control over the projects which will use this library so I can not edit their App.config file to set the log4net config. Is there a way to do this?